# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')

Tags: node.js, npm, cmd, yarnpkg, lerna

When trying to install `yarn install` in project folder getting me error

```
    yarn install v1.22.15 
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/typescript/-/typescript-4.3.5.tgz: 3224:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:c:\\ws\\deps\\openssl\\openssl\\ssl\\record\\ssl3_record.c:677:
".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "D:\\GitHub Projects\\wallet-adapter\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
node:_tls_wrap:411
        owner._tlsOptions.isServer ? 'server' : 'client', err,
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
    at TLSWrap.onerror (node:_tls_wrap:411:27)
```

Also same error occuring to me while trying to install `npm install --g lerna`

I'm trying these commands in CMD "Command Prompt"

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade the cypress to 12.6.0 version and migrate the code to the new version. That should work, it worked for me.

Comment: Confirmed this fixes the problem. I was running an older version of cypress when similar error started occurring out of nothing while running tests on a server that runs them daily for over a year now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).